# Unmarshalling xml schema choice element to separate Lists

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb, unmarshalling

Is it possible for a schema such as:

```
<xs:complexType name="GroupType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element type="PageType" name="Page" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>           
            <xs:element type="GroupType" name="Group" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>                
            <xs:element type="ResourcesType" name="Resources" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

..to be unmarshalled in such a way that the different element types are in separate lists? 
e.g:

```
public class GroupType {
    List<PageType> page;
    List<GroupType> group;
    ResourcesType resources;
    ...
}
```

The default behaviour of JAXB is to combine all the elements that match the `choice` into a single generic list. I don't care about ordering or recreating the exact document when marshalling, so it would be convenient to organise the data better rather than be an exact replica.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from POJOs you can annotate your class as follows:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class GroupType {
    @XmlElement(name="Page")
    List<PageType> page;

    @XmlElement(name="Group)
    List<GroupType> group;

    @XmlElement(name="Resources")
    ResourcesType resources;
    ...
}
```

If you are generating your classes from an XML schema, then you could use an external bindings file to specify that you have a pre-built class for `GroupType`

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/04/xml-schema-to-java-xsd-choice.html

Comment: I couldn't get this to work for me. I did realise though, without the maxOccurs the elements are put into their respective lists (not that it solves my problem..)